# Find coincidence between item in Firebase List and value provided

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

Sorry by my question. Maybe it's too evident, but I'm new in Ionic and I would like do the things the best as possible.

I have a barcode scanner that returns a value with the key of a collection in my firebase database. I need to know if the scanned code exists in my database. Up to this point this is what I have:

```
export class HomePage {

    constructor(
         private barcode: BarcodeScanner, 
         public navCtrl: NavController, 
         af: AngularFireDatabase) {

         // Here I get the list of elements where I will search the scanned code.
         this.ocupadas = af.list('/UbicacionesOcupadas', { 
             query: { 
                 orderByChild: 'evento', 
                 equalTo: 28 
             }
         });
      }

      // Here I get the QR Code value.
      async scanBarcode() {
          this.results = await this.barcode.scan(this.options);
      }

      // Now, I need to know if the QR Code value is in the firebase list. How would you do?
```

Comment: checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example using find to compare `this.results` against `this.ocupadas`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) to compare between the results.

```
public findScanAgainstStoredList(scannedItem){
   // scannedItem being this.results
   let item = this.ocupadas.find(scannedItem);
   if(item != undefined){
       // do something if there is an item
   }else{
       // do something if no item is found
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gerdi for your contribution. I tried using find but the Visual Studio Code returns an error: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'